# Splitted screens adjusting in ConEmu

Tags: windows, conemu

I usually use [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) on Linux, and of its features that I like is the ability to adjust the size of the splitted screens arbitrarily.

E.g:
http://oracleview.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/terminator-mad1.png

Does ConEmu have such feature? I just splitted the screen into 2 horizontal screen, but couldn't adjust the size. They seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create any wanted splits configuration. It allows to choose vert/horz and split percentage.

And there are hotkeys to manage splits (resizing and activating).

[image: Split screen hotkeys in ConEmu]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Being able to resize the splitted screens is convenient. Hopefully it will be released soon :)

Comment: This is one thing im missing :) I hope u will find the time to implement it. Thanks for conemu.

Comment: Implemented long ago... look in hotkeys ;-)

Comment: @Maximus is there a way to "unsplit" consoles without killing one or split an existing console (it seems the only way to make splits now involves new consoles)?

Comment: What is `Apps`?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html